# How to obtain grails domain uri when exposed as a rest resource?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have declared a domain class (Grails V2.4.3) as a rest resource like

```
import grails.rest.*

@Resource(uri="testData")
class TestData {
   String data


}
```

How can I get the uri of my rest resource in my controller code? For example:

```
class TestDataController {
   def index() {
     System.err.println("${TestData.uri()}") //print out domain uri here
   }
```